# Align equations on equal and vertical bars between equals

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, amsmath, vertical, bar

I am aligning some equations using the \begin{aligned} from amsmath package. This aligns the equations using the = as alignment point, which is nice, but I also want a vertical line drawn between every two = symbols. Essentially, I want to achieve this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this?
Many thanks

EDIT: here is the code I use now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
x &= 3+2 \\ 
  &= 5
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I sometimes use the line when showing computations on the blackboard, because the environment is much more cluttered than printed paper, so the line helps keeping things together. I find no use for it in a printout.

Comment: @egreg how do you do it?

Comment: @Patrik Well, on the blackboard I use no TeX macro, but chalk (or an electronic pen for virtual blackboards).

Comment: @egreg hahaha, right. I assumed you meant that you use a video projector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two possibilities: one based on `pstricks`, which allows for more complex ways to link two `=` signs (or actually any two elements in a formula), another with standard tools (`\stackrel` and `\smash`) which is  fine in this case:

```
\documentclass[11pt, svgnames]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\cvrule}{\smash{\color{SeaGreen}\rule{0.4pt}{2ex}}}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
x & \stackrel{\pnode{E1}}{=} 3 + 2 &\hspace{3em} x & = 3 + 2\\
  & \stackrel{\pnode{E2}}{=}5 & & \stackrel{\cvrule}{=} 5
\end{alignat*}
\ncline[linewidth=0.4pt, linecolor=Tomato, nodesepA=1.5ex]{E1}{E2}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I need. I chose the second possibility, as it does not require me to enable \write18

Answer (score 1):

Adapting my answer here: [Environment for joining continued equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/706920/environment-for-joining-continued-equations), you can create an `\equal` macro and a counter. The macro puts the equal symbol, and a `\tikzmarknode` from `tikzmark` Ti*k*Z library and draws the line to the previous equal (if there is any) in the same way that Bernard's answer, but using Ti*k*Z instead of PSTricks.

Note that if you use the macro several times you need to reset the counter.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcounter{NumberOfEquals}
\NewDocumentCommand{\equal}{}
{%
  \mathbin{\tikzmarknode{equal\theNumberOfEquals}{=}}%
  \ifnum\theNumberOfEquals>0%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\LastEqual{\theNumberOfEquals-1}%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\draw ([yshift=1pt]equal\theNumberOfEquals.north) -- (equal\LastEqual.south);%
  \fi%
  \stepcounter{NumberOfEquals}%
}

\begin{document}
Just follow the lines:
\begin{align*}
x & \equal 3+2 \\ 
  & \equal 5
\end{align*}

Let's do it again, but you now need to reset the counter:
\setcounter{NumberOfEquals}{0}
\begin{align*}
x & \equal 3+2 \\ 
  & \equal 5
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For simpler situation, I often use this handmade workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
x &= 3+2 \\[-1ex]
  & \, \, \, | \\[-1ex]
  &= 5
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Where [-1ex] reduces the vertical distance between the line above and below (can be adjusted).