# Environment for joining continued equations

Tags: align, environments

What I am looking for is an environment where the equal signs of the continued equations are joined automatically. The desired output is:

[image]

Currently I achieve this  by using the packages tikz and tikzmark in an non-convenient way.

```
\begin{align*}
   \phi &\ {\tikzmarknode{NA}=} \left(\frac{4\zeta}{1-z^{2}}\right)^{1/4}\\
        &\ {\tikzmarknode{NB}=} \sqrt{2}\zeta^{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{X}{X-1}\right)^{1/4}\\
        &\ {\tikzmarknode{NC}=} \sqrt{2}\zeta^{1/4}\gamma^{-1}
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
   \draw[overlay] (NA) -- (NB);
   \draw[overlay] (NB) -- (NC);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What would be useful is to write an new environment which automatically adds the tikzpicture and the nodes after the & character. Is there a simpler way to achieve the same effect, such that I could simply write:

```
\begin{conteqns}
  \phi &= \left(\frac{4\zeta}{1-z^2}\right)^{1/4}\\
       &= \sqrt{2}\zeta^{1/4}\left(\frac{X}{X-1}\right)^{1/4}\\
       &= \sqrt{2}\zeta^{1/4}\gamma^{-1}
\end{conteqns}
```

?

Comment: That may be good on the blackboard, when it's nearly full and the students need clues. I don't think it's useful in a well-typeset paper or book.

Comment: When you get a solution to your problem, it might also answer this related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/445973/36296

Answer (score 2):

This example could be a first (and slightly different) approach. It creates an `\equal` macro and a counter. The macro puts the equal symbol, the `\tikzmarknode` and draws the line to the previous equal (if there is any). Obviously, the counter numbers the equals/nodes.

**Edit:** Note that if you need more than one of such environments, you need to reset the counter:

```
\setcounter{NumberOfEquals}{0}
```

Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcounter{NumberOfEquals}
\NewDocumentCommand{\equal}{}
{%
  \mathbin{\tikzmarknode{equal\theNumberOfEquals}{=}}%
  \ifnum\theNumberOfEquals>0%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\LastEqual{\theNumberOfEquals-1}%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\draw ([yshift=1pt]equal\theNumberOfEquals.north) -- (equal\LastEqual.south);%
  \fi%
  \stepcounter{NumberOfEquals}%
}

\begin{document}
Just follow the lines:
% If this is not the first use:
\setcounter{NumberOfEquals}{0}
%
\begin{align*}
   \phi & \equal \left(\frac{4\zeta}{1-z^{2}}\right)^{1/4}\\
        & \equal \sqrt{2}\zeta^{\frac{1}{4}}\left(\frac{X}{X-1}\right)^{1/4}\\
        & \equal \sqrt{2}\zeta^{1/4}\gamma^{-1}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be nice if you could also answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445973/align-equations-on-equal-and-vertical-bars-between-equals

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, done!!

Comment: @ Juan Castaño Thanks!

Comment: Very useful! Thanks!